# releasing actionlistener before it is finished perfoming action

Tags: java, actionlistener

I've written a program that uses a button to trigger a loop but I would like the button to be released before the loop is finished executing so that it can be re-triggered if necessary.

here is the listener:

```
    // Play note
    btnPlay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            strum();
        }
    });
```

and this is the code it's executing:

```
public void strum() {
    int f = (Integer)frequency.getValue();
    double l = loss.getValue() / 1000.0;
    GuitarString note = new GuitarString(f, l);
    RealTimeAudio playback = new RealTimeAudio();

    int playTime = playback.getSampleRate(); // arbitrarily set to 1 second

    note.pluck();

    while (note.time() < playTime) {
        playback.play(note.sample());
        note.tic();
    }
}
```

any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run your strum() method in a different thread to get what you want.
There are a lot of ways doing this.
One is the swing worker:

```
new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        strum();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        //do something to clean up or so
    }
}.execute();
```

An other would be to use a Thread:

```
new Thread() {
  @Override public void run() {
    try {
        strum();
    } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
  }
}.start();
```